# Compare unkown number of items in an array in PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to compare the weight of 2 items in an array:

```
  if($resultados[0]['weight'] > $resultados[1]['weight']){
    echo $resultados[0]['modelo']." weighs more";
  }elseif($resultados[0]['weight'] < $resultados[1]['weight']){
    echo $resultados[1]['modelo']." weighs more";
  }
```

But if the array contains more than 2 items, it get more complicated. How can I echo the most heavy item if there are an unkown number of items?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
max(array_column($resultados, 'weight')));
```

**UPDATE**

if you need the whole item use the reduce function:

```
 $item = array_reduce($resultados, function ($current, $next) {
    return @$current['weight'] > $next['weight'] ? $current: $next;
});
```

Comment: That would get the max weight but how can I select the 'modelo' value which correspond to that max weight?

Answer (score 0):

Using original Youba answer I did

```
$max_w = max(array_column($resultados,'peso'));
foreach($resultados as $res){
  if(in_array($max_w,$res)){
    echo $res['modelo']." weighs more";
  }
}
```

Which seems to work fine unless 2 items are the same weight.